# Number of pies and sides combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I sell 5 inch savory pies with sides and gravy
I am trying to calculate how many possible combinations / options my customers have

Simple variables we offer
8 pies
5 sides
2 gravies

The variables can only include ONE pie but can have ANY combination of sides and gravy i.e. ZER0 sides and gravy up to all sides and all gravies

COMPLICATED

We have all pies also available in

(A) 2 more sizes (3 " slider and 9" family)
(B) 3 of the  5" pies also avail in gluten free shells

Thanks!

Comment: The tag on this should probably be [combinatorics] rather than [multivariable-calculus]. Also, it sounds like it might possibly be [homework].

Comment: Thanks it's not homework - it's my pie shop. And I'm crap at maths

Comment: That makes sense. The second sentence was an afterthought.

Answer (score 3):

In general, when you have multiple categories and must pick one item from each category, you multiply the number of choices present. Also, for a set with $n$ elements, we have $2^n$ possible subsets since each element can be either included or excluded(2 choices for each of the n options). Now we apply this logic to the problem:

For the simple variables, you have 8 pie choices.  For sides, the number of possible subsets of 5 sides is $2^5 = 32$.  For gravy, we similarly have $2^2 = 4$ possible choices. This gives $$8 * 32 * 4 = 1024$$ combinations.

The complicated options bring the total number of pie choices up to $8 * 3 + 3 = 31$, since you are adding two new sizes and also 3 new individual pies.  However, the gravy and sides do not change. This brings the total up to $$31 * 32 * 4 = 3968$$ possibilities.